# Limiting API searches to pages of a specific category

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I would like to search Facebook pages restricted to the "Musician/band" category. I tried querying by adding "category=Musician/band" to my URL (as shown in the URL below), but this did not seem to change the response.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?    fields=name,location,category&q="+request.term+"&type=page&category=Musician/band
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not a supported use-case in the search API, you'd need to do client-side filtering of the result set